# How does Software CEF (Cisco`s techonology) implement prefix search algorithm?

Tags: cisco, routing, cef

How does the software version of CEF (Cisco`s technology for speeding up packet switching) implement algorithm to search prefixes in FIB (Forwarding Information Base)?

Does it use a hash table or tree-based search algorithm, or what does it use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CEF uses a trie:

[*How to Choose the Best Router Switching Path for Your Network*](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/ip/express-forwarding-cef/13706-20.html)

> **Cisco Express Forwarding**
>
> Cisco Express Forwarding, also uses a 256 way data structure to store
>   forwarding and MAC header rewrite information, but it does not use a
>   tree. Cisco Express Forwarding uses a trie, which means the actual
>   information being searched for is not in the data structure; instead,
>   the data is stored in a separate data structure, and the trie simply
>   points to it.
>
> [image]
>
> This separation of the reachability information (in the Cisco Express
>   Forwarding table) and the forwarding information (in the adjacency
>   table), provides a number of benefits:
>
> - The adjacency table can be built separately from the Cisco Express    Forwarding table, allowing both to build without process switching 
>     any packets.
> - The MAC header rewrite used to forward a packet is not stored in    cache entries, so changes in a MAC header rewrite string do not 
>     require invalidation of cache entries.
> - You can point directly to the forwarding information, rather than to    the recursed next hop, in order to resolve recursive routes.
>
> Essentially, all cache aging is eliminated, and the cache is pre-built
>   based on the information contained in the routing table and ARP cache.
>   There is no need to process switch any packet to build a cache entry.
>   Other Entries in the Adjacency Table
>
> The adjacency table can contain entries other than MAC header rewrite
>   strings and outbound interface information. Some of the various types
>   of entries that can be placed in the adjacency table include:
>
> - **cache**—A MAC header rewrite string and outbound interface used to    reach a particular adjacent host or router.
> - **receive**—Packets destined to this IP address should be received by the router. This includes broadcast addresses and addresses
>     configured on the router itself.
> - **drop**—Packets destined to this IP address should be dropped. This    could be used for traffic denied by an access list, or routed
>     to a NULL interface.
> - **punt**—Cisco Express Forwarding cannot switch this packet; pass it to    the next best switching method (generally fast switching) for
>     processing.
> - **glean**—The next hop is directly attached, but there are no MAC header    rewrite strings currently available.